# Access filenames of files that are not in Isolated Storage on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, file-io

Is it possible to access folders/files that you provide with an app (not in Isolated Storage)?

I have a set of alarm sounds for my app and want the user to be able to pick the one they want to use. I just want access to the filenames so that I can build a list for the user to pick from. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create an XML file with a list of paths to your files.
For ex.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestsURIsList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <URIs>
    <TestUri>
      <TestName>Short funny test</TestName>
      <TestDesc>Thus it's a very small test that contains only 2 questions it can tell you a lot about yourself. Just try it and you'll see :)</TestDesc>
      <ImageURI>img/questionblack.JPG</ImageURI>
      <TestXMLSource>ReadyTests/SmallestTest.xml</TestXMLSource>
      <CustomURIPage />
    </TestUri>

    <TestUri>
      <TestName>Tsukanov's test</TestName>
      <TestDesc>Learn you own time unit and all the information it can give</TestDesc>
      <ImageURI>TsukanovTest/temperaments_small.png</ImageURI>
      <TestXMLSource />
      <CustomURIPage>/TsukanovTest/TsukanovTestPage.xaml</CustomURIPage>
    </TestUri>
  </URIs>
```

Than you open this file with an xml reader and parse and show to a user.
Hope it helps